# table-valued function, returning no value?

Tags: sql-server-2008, table-valued-parameters

this is my function:

```
create function ReservationByClient (@reservation_ID int)
returns table
as

    return(
    select 
    c.client_name,
    c.client_surname,
    c.client_passport,
    r.aptID,
    r.start_date,
    r.end_date,
    r.confirmation
    from tblClient c 
    inner join  tblReservation r on r.client_ID=c.client_ID
    where r.reservation_ID=@reservation_ID)
```

when invoked with:

```
select * from dbo.ReservationByClient (602)
```

it returns only column names and no values in it even there are existing records in both tables, eg. there are three reservations for the same client.

one more question:
can i get results only for confirmed reservations (field confirmed is bit type)

thanks

Comment: You're going to need to post some data from your tables, I think. And your question says "eg there are three reservations for the same client," but the parameter to your function is taking a *reservation* id, so part of me wonders if there's something confused there.. (hence the need to see some data).

Comment: Maybe you have some inconsistency in schemes?

Comment: table tblReservations has folowing fields: 
reservation_ID (int), aptID (int), client_ID (int), 
start_date (datetime), end_date (datetime), 
details (nvarchar(max)), confirmation (bit)
table tblClients has folowing fields:
client_id (int), Client_name(nvarchar(50)), client_surname(nvarchar(50)), client_passport (nvarchar(50))

for client_ID=2 there are 3 existing reservations in tblReservation

Comment: Do you have a reservation row with reservation_ID=602?  if so, does the client_id on this row exist in the clients table?

Comment: no, that was the problem, i deleted that id, thanks